# Conditional variance and normal approximation

Tags: probability

A club is established with $2000$ members, $1000$ of exact age $35$ and $1000$ of exact age $45$.

You are given:

(i) Probability of someone aged $35$ surviving in $30$ years = $0.8$ and

(ii)Probability of someone aged $45$ surviving in $30$ years = $0.55$

(iii) Future lifetimes are independent.

(iv) $N$ is the random variable for the number of members still alive $30$ years
after the club is established.

Using the normal approximation, calculate the smallest $n$ such that $P(N \geq n) \leq 0.05$. (use $z = 1.645$)

If there is $1200$ members aged $35$ and $800$ members aged $45$, calculate the smallest $n$.

**Attempt:**  I would like to find the $\mathbb{E}[N]$ and $Var[N]$. Finding $\mathbb{E}[N]$ is easy ($1350$ for $1000:1000$ ratio and $1400$ for $1200:800$ ratio)

My attempt on $Var(N)$ goes like this. I first consider that there is only $1$ person in the group where the probability of him being $35$ or $45$ years old is $0.5$ respectively.

Using Bernoulli shortcut, Variance for that. I tried using substitution for $0.5*0.5*(0.8-0.55)^2 = 0.015625$

Since there are $2000$ random variable, $Var(N) = 2000*0.015625=31.25$.

When I try to use $\mathcal{N} \sim (1350,31.25)$, I found out that my answer is not the same as what's written in the solution.

I am now considering using $Var(X) = \mathbb{E}(Var(X|Y))+Var(E(X|Y))$ but I am still stuck for the time being.

Other than the correct solution, an explanation of why my solution is wrong would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $N_1$ and $N_2$ the numbers of members still alive 30 years after which are 35 years old and 45 years old, respectively. Of course, $N = N_1 + N_2$.

$N_1$ is a binomial random variable with parameter $n_1 = 1000$ and $p_1= 0.8$, while $N_2$ is a binomial random variable with parameter $n_2 = 1000$ and $p_2= 0.55$.

We can evaluate the average of $N$:

$$\mu_N = \mathbb{E}[N] = \mathbb{E}[N_1] + \mathbb{E}[N_2] = \mu_{N_{1}} + \mu_{N_{2}} = \\
= n_1p_1 + n_2p_2 = 800+550 = 1350.$$

The variance of $N$ is:

$$\sigma_N^2= \mathbb{E}[(N-\mu_N)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(N_1 - \mu_{N_1} + N_2 - \mu_{N_2})^2] = \\
=\mathbb{E}[(N_1 - \mu_{N_1})^2] + \mathbb{E}[(N_2 - \mu_{N_2})^2] + 2\mathbb{E}[(N_1 - \mu_{N_1})(N_2 - \mu_{N_2})] =\\ 
=\sigma_{N_1}^2 + \sigma_{N_2}^2 + 2\mathbb{E}[(N_1 - \mu_{N_1})(N_2 - \mu_{N_2})].$$

Since $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent, then $\mathbb{E}[(N_1 - \mu_{N_1})(N_2 - \mu_{N_2})] = 0$, and hence:

$$\sigma_N^2 = \sigma_{N_1}^2 + \sigma_{N_2}^2 = n_1p_1(1-p_1) + n_2p_2(1-p_2) = 160 + 247.5 = 407.5$$

Using the normal approximation, then we want to find $n$ such that:

$$P(N \geq n) = 0.05$$

Passing to a standard normal random variable $Z = \frac{N-\mu_N}{\sigma_N}$, we have:

$$P\left(\frac{N-\mu_N}{\sigma_N} \geq \frac{n-\mu_N}{\sigma_N}\right) = 0.05 \\
P\left(Z \geq \frac{n-\mu_N}{\sigma_N}\right) = 0.05$$

We know that $P\left(Z \geq 1.645\right) = 0.05$, and hence:

$$ \frac{n-\mu_N}{\sigma_N} = 1.645 \Rightarrow n = 1.645\sigma_N+\mu_N = \\
= 1.645 \cdot \sqrt{407.5} + 1350 \simeq 1383$$